# getting Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority inside google cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

When running commands inside google cloud shell, I'm receiving this error "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" I've read that running `gcloud container clusters get-credentials YOURCLUSTERHERE --zone YOURCLUSTERZONEHERE` can solve this issue, but is this necessary when you are using an authorized google cloud shell session?

---

I run into this error when trying to run any `kubectl` command against my only cluster in the current project

Comment: Which server you are trying to connect to? Also, add the command you used, to the question.

Comment: If you are running `kubectl` in Cloud Shell, then you'll need to run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials YOURCLUSTERHERE --zone YOURCLUSTERZONEHERE`

Comment: Potential causes for this issue can be the refresh token in the kubeconfig getting expired. As mentioned in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/1.5/troubleshooting#kubeconfig_to_access_cluster) , running the `login` command again can resolve this issue.